# How to create a Ext.util.MixedCollection from a array on the fly

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a array

```
[object_1,object_2,object_n]
```

Now I want to create a Ext.util.MixedCollection from it without to need to first create it and afterwards add the data. Looking at the constructor there are no arguments capable of these and adding all to the items array but that will still leave the need for the keys...

Comment: Have you tried addAll() along with a custom getKey() method for the case you don't want it to be `id`

Comment: @sra not until now. Ok with this method the adding would be much cleaner but it is still not on the fly because the addAll() has no return value :(

Comment: @sra I didn't found any other solution then your's so please post your comment as answer that I can accept it.

Comment: Downvoted because the question should be rephrased to show the asker's actual intent based on sra's answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `addAll()` along with a custom `getKey()` method for the case you don't want it to be `id`?

Comment: @Reimius Dunno, I just have done what the OP asked me for. There was a reason why I just posted this as comment ;)

Comment: Yeah, I posted on the question too.  Stuff like this bothers me because it's not very valuable to other people who are looking for an answer to the same question.  You're not at fault for it, which is why I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 4):

There's no standard way to accomplish this, but there are a couple solutions.

### Factory Method

Change the name of the function to whatever you'd like, and you're all set.

```
MyApp.toMixedCollection = function (array, keyFn) {
    var mc = new Ext.util.MixedCollection(false, keyFn);
    mc.addAll(Ext.Array.from(array));
    return mc;
};
```

### Extend `Ext.util.MixedCollection`

I prefer this solution myself. Extending the class allows you to redefine the constructor params as an object rather than two separate params. Use the `items` config to load the object at creation time. As a bonus, you can also use the `listeners` config which is listed in the docs but doesn't actually work.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.MixedCollection', {
    extend: 'Ext.util.MixedCollection',

    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;

        me.listeners = config.listeners;
        me.callParent([config.allowFunctions, config.keyFn]);

        if (config.items) {
            me.addAll(config.items);
        }
    }
});

// Example usage
var mc = new MyApp.util.MixedCollection({
    keyFn: function (o) {
        return o.name;
    },
    items: [{
        name: 'A',
        foo:  'bar'
    },{
        name: 'B',
        foo:  'quo'
    }],
    listeners: {
        add: function () {
            console.log('added an object');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric and thank you for your reply on this. But basically I think this is the same as sra wrote, just wrapped up and my goal is to not wrapp all up, therefore I will stay with to lines of code instead of my prefered one line. Because sra was the faster one who answered I will accept his but you got my upvote for the response! Thank you again!